# Parent page shows no child content

Tags: pages, homepage, theme-options

I just installed a fresh copy of Wordpress and tried to create one parent page, but the page shows no content, regardless of which Official WP theme I use or if I use this new parent page as the static homepage or not.

[image]

[image]

However, the child pages are showing the parent-child permalink:

[image]

I'm running a localhost install under Windows 10, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4.

I honestly don't understand why I cannot use this feature anywhere.

What is happening? Isn't this supposed to be an out-of-the-box ready feature?

Comment: When you set a Page as the Front Page, only its content - i.e. content you add in the Editor in wp-admin - will show up. It does not automatically contain a loop to display recent posts like typical WP homepages tend to show, unless you set up a custom theme with a template for that Page.

Comment: So what is the purpose of the parent page attribute then? I had the impression that when you assign child pages to a parent page, the content would show up in the parent page, one after the other, using the order attrubute as well. Is this not so?

Comment: That is not so, if a theme implements it that way then yes, but that is rare. Parent pages are useful as they provide structure. For example i might have a portfolio page, with subpages for each project. I might show this structure via a widget, or show it in the menu, but I wouldn't expect a theme to automatically do this unless it explicitly advertised that it did so. The frontpage/blog page feature is the exception, and it has _special_ behaviour, namely it allows you to show a page instead of a list of posts on the homepage

Comment: Also note the permalink/URL changes that post parent makes

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the documentation. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: It sounds like what you might be looking for is something like the Category/Post relationship. Each Post can belong to a Category, and the Category can show either excerpts of multiple Posts or full Posts, which varies a bit by theme. This gives you very similar permalinks to parent/child Pages but provides an automated way to show some of the individual Posts' content all gathered together at one URL.

Answer (score 1):

> I just installed a fresh copy of Wordpress and tried to create one parent page

Pages are just pages, there's nothing special about parent pages, and it's not a term normally used

> but the page shows no content

If the page has no content, then there is no content to show

> regardless of which Official WP theme I use

Themes display pages the same, some may provide page templates or style them differently, but pages should work the same everywhere

> or if I use this new parent page as the static homepage or not.

A static homepage is just a way to show a single pages content on the homepage, instead of a list of the most recent posts

> I'm running a localhost install under Windows 10, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4.

Your environment has nothing to do with your issue here

> I honestly don't understand why I cannot use this feature anywhere.

I believe the problem here is a misunderstanding. The feature you're trying to use does not and never did exist.

> What is happening? Isn't this supposed to be an out-of-the-box ready feature?

No. I think I've pieced together what this feature is:

> If you have a page "A", then set it as the parent of B C and D, then B C and D will appear at the bottom of page A as sub-sections

No such feature exists unless you build a page template to do that. This is not the purpose of post parents.

In fact I would argue your mental model is upside down. In WordPress people don't think of pages as parents, but they think of pages as children/sub-pages.

Consider this scenarios:

I have a *services* page, and I provide these services:

- plumbing
- painting
- wiring

And for each service I want an about page, and a pricing page. So, I may setup a `services` page, then give it 3 subpages for each service, and 2 subpages for each of those named about and pricing, e.g.:

- services

  - plumbing

    - about
    - prices
  - painting

    - about
    - prices
  - wiring

    - about
    - prices

If we look at the painting prices page, it'll have the URL `/services/painting/prices`